# Does $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin\left(x \sin \left( \frac 1x \right) \right)}{x \sin \left( \frac 1x \right)}$ exist?

Tags: limits, continuity, epsilon-delta

I was playing around with the function $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, defined as follows.
$$f(x) = \frac{\sin\left(x \sin \left( \frac 1x \right) \right)}{x \sin \left( \frac 1x \right)}$$
This function is undefined at $x = \frac{1}{n\pi}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Namely, this suggests

$$\forall \delta > 0 : \exists x : 0 < |x| < \delta \wedge f(x) \text{ is undefined.}$$

I'm curious about $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$. If this value exists, say set $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = L$, we naturally must have that

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 : \exists \delta > 0 : 0 < |x| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon.$$

But, since $f$ is not defined for all $x$ in the set $0 < |x| < \delta$, the conclusion $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$ cannot always be guaranteed to hold. So, I'm inclined to say that the limit $L$ does not exist.

That being said, the graph looks like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0mnuexvgvz) and based on the graph, $f$ appears to satisfy this inequality:
$$\forall x : \frac{\sin x}{x} \leq f(x) < 1$$

Since $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$, this suggests in a squeeze-theorem-esque way that $L$ "wants" to take the value $1$, but of course we cannot actually apply the squeeze theorem here for the same reason that we couldn't apply the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition directly.

So, my questions are:

1. Is my analysis correct that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin\left(x \sin \left( \frac 1x \right) \right)}{x \sin \left( \frac 1x \right)}$ does not exist?
2. Is there any looser definition of a limit in common use (say, ${\lim}^\star$) that would set $\displaystyle {\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}}^\star \frac{\sin\left(x \sin \left( \frac 1x \right) \right)}{x \sin \left( \frac 1x \right)} = 1$ in a way that captures the spirit of what I described above?

Comment: Well, perhaps the term $x\sin \frac 1x$ could be "unwound" a bit by substitution of $y=\frac 1x$, then $\frac 1y\sin y$ would be a more "stable" quantity and perhaps the limit could be determined...

Comment: More specifically, for all $y_0\in[0,\pi)\cup(\pi,2\pi)$ you have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{y_0+n\pi}\sin(y_0+n\pi)=0$...

Comment: Your limit exists. See the general definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#More_general_subsets

Comment: Since $\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1$, there is no harm in extending the value of $\sin t/t$ ad $1$ when $t=0$. Notice that $x\sin(1/x)\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow0}0$ and so, your limit exists (and equals 1).

Comment: [Related 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2889055/505767) and  [Related 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4525761/505767)

Comment: Somewhat related -- [my comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4542773/how-do-we-classify-countably-infinite-holes-in-a-finite-range#comment9552548_4542773) to [How do we classify countably infinite holes in a finite range?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4542773/13130)

Answer (score 2):

First of all the limit exists: if you substitute $y=x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ then you have $y \to 0$ for $x \to 0$ (sin is a bounded function so $\lim_{x \to 0} x\sin\frac{1}{x} = 0$). So  $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(x\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x\sin(\frac{1}{x})}=\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin(y)}{y}=1$. Secondly of course if $f$ in $x$ is not defined also $f(x)-L$ is not defined, in the definition of a limit you have that all $x$ have to be in the domain of $f$.

Comment: What's the justification that a substitution like that is valid?

Comment: It's a theorem https://math.stackexchange.com/a/167948/1139301

Comment: Oh nice! I had entirely forgotten about limit substitutions lol. Originally I was thinking of using sandwich theorem on y=-x^2+1 and y=1 but was afraid it wouldn’t be as rigorous as needed. This works much better imo

Answer (score 0):

While $f$ is undefined at $\frac{1}{n\pi}$ the limits $\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{1}{n\pi}}f(x)$ seem to exist according to the visualization (you would have to check that) so you could consider the continuous extension of $f$ and take $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}$ of that.

Comment: Thank you, yes, that's basically the closest thing I had in mind.